# Dropdown based on table with additional custom value, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, selection

So, I can use the following to make a select box based on a database object

```
 <%= f.collection_select :role, Role.where(company: current_company), :name, :name %>
```

I want to be able to add custom fields on top of it, such as an "all" or "none" selection, how do I do it, do I have to add temporary rows to the active record object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include a blank value with `:include_blank` as an option parameter.

Any more control and you'll need to manually build the options for the [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) with select and [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) or [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select). That may sound a little more difficult, but it actually isn't that bad.

```
<%= f.select :role, options_for_select([["none", "None"], ["all", "All"]]) +  options_from_collection_for_select(Role.where(company: current_company), :name, :name) %>
```

Here we're just concatenating two strings of option markup.

Comment: The rails API documentation should better explain the API for `:include_blank` than I can here. http://api.rubyonrails.org/ and search for collection_select.